# Change font size of popular tags

Tags: php, mysql

I have a few *static* tags in a table.

And I'm trying to track clicks on the static tags, and i have seen on other sites (and it actually really good) that the popular tags changes is size.

Have a look at this image:
[image]
This image presents the expected output.

The table looks like this:

```
+-----------+--------+
|    tag    | clicks |
+-----------+--------+
| Falun     | 45     |
| Stockholm | 229    |
| Borlänge  | 77     |
| ...       | ...    |
| ...       | ...    |
+-----------+--------+
```

More clicks, the "bigger" font size. But font size should be max 40px, and min 5px.

How can I from MySQL and PHP calculate difference in clicks and present it in `font-size`?

`SELECT tag, (SELECT COUNT(percentage) FROM tags) AS tag_size FROM tags`

Then

```
foreach($tags as $tag){
    <a href="#" style="font-size: <?php echo $tag->tag_size ?>px"><?php echo $tag->tag ?></a>
}
```

Very sorry for pseudo code, but i have no idea how to do this!

Comment: What is the database structure? What is `percentage`?

Comment: I'm sorry for the pseudo code, percentage should be symbolizing "the font size". The table structure is `tag` and `clicks`

Comment: So what are you counting? `SELECT COUNT(percentage) FROM tags`

Comment: I want to count  the difference in clicks. When I'm giving it a thought right now i might be overthinking it. Maybe the right way to go is just `if($value->clicks > 10){echo '10';}else if($value->clicks >20){echo '20';}.... and so on` So the more represented a tag is in clicks, the bigger the `font-size`, according to image.

Comment: Yea, you could that probably want to pull the max clicks first so you can set that to 40. I still don't know what your SQL is counting though. Do you have one record per keyword click?

Comment: Yes one record per click, to avoid multipel IP "multi-clicking". My SQL in the Q is not doing anything, it is pseudo code so you guys would know what my intentions was. Thanks @chris85

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find the maximum number of clicks:

```
SELECT MAX(`clicks`) FROM `tags`;
```

Let's assume this is assigned to a variable called `$max_clicks`. You then need to scale the point sizes according to this value. The formula you use to do this is entirely up to you, but scaling according to the square root of the click count should produce reasonable results:

```
if ($max_clicks > 0) { // Avoid divide-by-zero error if nothing has been clicked
  $sqrt_max_clicks = sqrt($max_clicks);
  $query = "SELECT `tag`, 5 + 35 * SQRT(`clicks`) / $sqrt_max_clicks FROM `tags`;"
  // ... (Generate tag markup) ...
}
```

Obviously, `5` is the minimum point size, and `35` is the difference between the maximum and minimum point sizes. I'm assuming here that you want tags to appear in the tag list even if they have a click count of zero.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use `group by` to pull all the tag records together. Then you can use `if`s to set your font size. Something like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT tag, count(clicks) AS tag_size FROM tags group by tag';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row) {
    $size = $row['tag_size'];
    if($size >700 ){
        $font_size = 40;
    } elseif($size >650 ){
        $font_size = 39;
    } elseif($size >650 ){
        $font_size = 38;
    }...
    else {
        $font_size = 5;
}
```

Comment: This will fail as the click count grows. Soon, even the most unpopular tags might have over 700 clicks. I get the impression that the OP wants the relative tag clicks as a percentage rather than an arbitrary number. IE the most popular tag being 100 percent. This way each tag can be rendered as x percent of 40px (the max font size)

Comment: If there are only 2 tags though and one has `1` click and the other has `1000` I think the `1000` should be 40pxs and the `1` click 5pxs because it is so unpopular. Depends on OPs intent though; I'll await an update.